# While trying to get relational value system console generates exception

Tags: apex

I am getting

> "Line: 24, Column: 1 System.SObjectException: SObject row was
>   retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field:
>   Account.Contact__r"

Here is my Code can you please help me out to find relational object's
 field value

```
String sTemp = 'Contact__r.CreatedBy.profileid';
public String getAllQuery {get;set;}
List<Schema.SObjectField> tempFields;
public Id oid = '00128000003P6nL';
public SObject resultObject {get;set;}
public List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> fields {get;set;}
public static final String ERROR_ID_MISSING = 'There was no id passed in the parameters. Id is required.';
public static final String QUERY_SELECT = 'select ';
public static final String QUERY_FROM = ' from ';
public static final String QUERY_WHERE = ' where Id = \'';
fields = new List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = oid.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();
  tempFields = fieldMap.values();
  for(Schema.SObjectField sof : tempFields){
    fields.add(sof.getDescribe());
  }
  getAllQuery = buildQueryAllString(fields,objDescribe,oid);
  resultObject = Database.query(getAllQuery);
  if(sTemp.contains('.')){
    String[] arrTest = sTemp.split('\\.');
    String sRelatedValue = '';
    sObject tempObject ;
    tempObject = (SObject)resultObject.getSObject(arrTest[0]);
  }
public String buildQueryAllString(List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> queryFields,DescribeSObjectResult obj, String theId){
  String query = QUERY_SELECT;
  for(Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr : queryFields)
  {
      query = query + dfr.getName() + ',';
  }
  query = query.subString(0,query.length() - 1);
  query = query + QUERY_FROM;
  query = query + obj.getName();
  query = query + QUERY_WHERE;
  query = query + theId + '\'';
  system.debug('Build Query == ' + query);
  return query;
}
```

Comment: Account.Contact__r yo are trying to access this without querying. Please check these lines    if(sTemp.contains('.')){
    String[] arrTest = sTemp.split('\\.');
    String sRelatedValue = '';
    sObject tempObject ;
    tempObject = (SObject)resultObject.getSObject(arrTest[0]);
  }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have built a function to query all of the fields on a particular object - Account in this case, base on the value stored in `oid`.

After performing that query, you are trying to retrieve the value of the field named: `Contact__r`. This is where the error occurs. There is no field named `Contact__r` (or `profileid` for that matter) on the Account object.

Even if you left the `sTemp` string intact instead of `split`ting it, you would still run into this same type of error because `buildQueryAllString` only queries fields on one object, and doesn't query fields on related objects.

In your `sTemp` string, `Contact__r.CreatedBy.profileid`, you are traversing two relationships. You go from the `Account` to a `Contact` to a `User`; It is the `User` object where the `profileid` is actually located.

Comment: There is a custom field in Account, Contact
Contact__c Lookup(Contact)  Than why it's throwing exception for Contact Relation

Comment: @kumargaurav : So, when you set a value for that look-up relationship, you will have an id value for the field Contact__c on Account. Your query that gets generated in `buildQueryAllString` will only get that id value. It won't get the value of any of the fields on the Contact object.

Comment: Ok i missed that, now  i think i should query again in base of contactid like i have query for Account in base of Id

Comment: @kumargaurav : If you just want to get the id of the Contact, you can do a query for the `Contact__c` field. If you want to get the Id of the owner of that Contact, you can query for `Contact__r.OwnerId`. Keep in mind though that the `__r` notation can't be used alone.

Comment: @kumargaurav With what you already have, it would probably be easiest to just query again once you get the id since you already have the function to get all fields on an object just from an id. Keep in mind though that this probably not the best option performance-wise. In general, you want to use as few queries as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As @martin has pointed out you are missing the child relations in your query and trying to access them in your results set.
Use [`getChildRelationShips()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getChildRelationships) on your `objDescribe` instance and collect the required child fields as well to pass into the query. [ChildRelationShip](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm) Class also may helpful for you.

Comment: The relationship is the other way around. The field is on Account, looking up a Contact.